# How to install a whole directory of files with Homebrew?

Tags: installation, homebrew

I'm using Homebrew to install a script, which depends on a directory of resources being in the same directory as the script. For example:

```
.
├── directory/
└── script.sh
```

How do I make a directory where `script.sh` is install with Homebrew? I have tried my formula as:

```
class Script < Formula
  ...
  def install
    bin.install "script.sh"
    bin.install "directory/"
  end
end
```

The problem is that both `script.sh` and `directory/` are installed to `/usr/local/Cellar/script/`, but only `script.sh` is installed to `/usr/local/bin/`.

I have also tried replacing `bin.install "directory/` with `bin.install Dir["directory/"]`, but it did not resolve the issue.

How would I make it so `script.sh` can see `directory/`, which is in `/usr/local/Cellar/script/directory/`, from within my formula? Can I symlink from `/usr/local/bin` within my formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common pattern in Homebrew formulae. The solution is not to install the directory under `bin/`, as that directory is supposed to contains executables only, but rather to install both the script and the directory in some place, then create a wrapper in `bin/` that calls the script from that place.

1. Install everything under `libexec`:

   ```
    libexec.install Dir["*"]
   ```
2. Write a wrapper in `bin`:

   ```
    bin.write_exec_script libexec/"script.sh"
   ```

Full formula:

```
class Myformula < Formula
  desc "..."
  homepage "..."
  url "..."
  sha256 "..."
  
  def install
    libexec.install Dir["*"]
    bin.write_exec_script libexec/"script.sh"
  end
end
```